# How to delete registry key

Tags: install4j

I am trying to delete the registry key using below API, but not deleted

```
WinRegistry.deleteKey(RegistryRoot.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\My App", false);
```

Please help me to delete the registry key.

Comment: Is this the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828316/how-to-save-registry-key-to-file ?

Comment: yes. resolved with below solution

Comment: you need elevated privileges to do that. If you do this in a "Run script" action, set its "Action elevation type" property to "Elevate to maximum available privileges". A "Request privileges" action must have been executed successfully for that to have an effect.