# How to save registry key to a file

Tags: java, install4j

I am trying to save the registry key to file using the below API, but save failed.

```
String key = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\My App";
String fileName = "myapp.reg";
WinRegistry.saveKey(RegistryRoot.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key, fileName);
```

Registry key snippet

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\\my app]
"DisplayName"="my app"
"DisplayIcon"="C:\\myapp\\.install4j\\installer.ico"
"UninstallString"="\"C:\\myapp\\uninstall.exe\""
"InstallLocation"="C:\myapp"
"DisplayVersion"="3.3.3"
"VersionMajor"=dword:00000003
"VersionMinor"=dword:00000003
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need elevated privileges to do that. If you do this in a "Run script" action, set its "Action elevation type" property to "Elevate to maximum available privileges". A "Request privileges" action must have been executed successfully for that to have an effect.

To do this in any script wrap your code like this:

```
context.runElevated(new RemoteCallable() {
    public Serializable execute() {
        // run registry code here
        return null;
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Please accept my answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: gave you an upvote Ingo, bc I have never seen a simple way to request elevation as you have shown here